# wordpress custom post type slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named `car` which stores all the cars.
It has a rewrite slug `'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'cars', with_front' => false],`

I want every car to be accessed from this URL ONLY: e.g. `/cars/bmw-328i`.
However when I enter `/bmw-328i` without the slug, it still redirects to `/cars/bmw-328i` where I expected it to be a 404 not found.

Which settings did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the WordPress canonical redirects. Add the following code to the active theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'dcs_no_redirect_on_404');
function dcs_no_redirect_on_404($redirect_url)
{
    if (is_404()) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Comment: However, if you want to get the code for creating the custom post types, you can refer to the following URL:
https://tutsocean.com/wordpress-code-generators/wordpress-custom-post-type-cpt/